# How do you make a arabic sounding flute in reaper or bandlab?

Tags: jazz, folk, genre-characteristics, drums

I'm making an Arabic jazz album for a music class project, that's kinda like *the astounding eyes of rita* album by Anouar Brahem, and in the album there's a lot flute and Arabic percussion in the album, and I was wondering about how to recreate that style of music for my album using bandlab.

Comment: How far have you got? Where are you stuck?

Comment: wouldn't this be more relevant on https://music.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB - no. It shows no research effort. it's looking for a full soup to nuts tutorial.